# Destructuring state assignment with logical operators

Tags: javascript, eslint

On `this.state.keyboard` ESLint gives me the error "Must use destructuring state assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)".

```js
const keyboard = this.state.keyboard || data[0];
```

Of course, I can do something like:

```js
let {keyboard} = this.state;
keyboard = keyboard || data[0];
```

But is there a way to do it in one line and using `const`?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `const { keyboard = data[0] } = this.state` but that doesn't have same function entirely as the logical OR accounts for falsey values.

Comment: You also have the alternative of ignoring the warning for class members: `ignoreClassFields` setting will accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it in one line with `const` and get the exact same behaviour as you have, i.e, to assign `data[0]` to keyboard if it is falsy.

If you destructure keyboard and give it a default value like this:

```
const { keyboard = data[0] } = this.state;
```

`keyboard` will be set to `data[0]` only if it is defined in `this.state`. And the same happens with this statement:

```
const { keyboard } = { keyboard: data[0], ...this.state };
```

Comment: Note this isn't exactly functionally equivalent to the OP's code as this only defers to `data[0]` when `keyboard` is undefined, rather than it just being falsey

Comment: Even the second solution it's not really equivalent but it works in my case, thank you.